# Example of projection sequence on Hilbert space with strong limit P

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $P_n$ be strongly convergent with limit $P$, where $P_n$'s are projections on a Hilbert space $H$.Suppose that $P_n(H)$ is infinite dimensional. Show by example that P(H)$ may be finite dimensional.

Maybe consider the closed subspace of the $l^2$ space. But How can I define the $P_n$ sequence which is infinte dimensioanl.Then it's limit $P(H)$ is finite dimensional ?

$P_1x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_1,0,x_2,0,x_3,0...)$
$P_2x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_1,0,0,0,x_5,0,0,0,x_9...)$ 
What should be $P_nx$ ? and what about $Px$ which is finite dimensional?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Have you made any progress on this problem? Questions are usually received better if there is some demonstration of work/progress on the problem

Comment: Just, Maybe, $P_n$ should be increasing sequence.But I dont know How can I find the example which is satisfy that $P(H)$ is finite dimensional

Comment: If each $P_n$ should have infinite-dimensional range, and the limit should have finite-dimensional range, it would make more sense to take a decreasing sequence.

Comment: I see, But How can define the decreasing sequence ?

Comment: $\ell^2$ is a good choice. Now, the simplest projections are those that set some components to $0$ and leave the others unchanged. When does such a projection have infinite-dimensional image?

Comment: $P_1x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_1,0,x_2,0,x_3,0...)$
$P_2x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,...)=(x_1,0,0,0,x_5,0,0,0,x_9...)$\\
$\vdots$ \linebreak
What should be $P_nx$ ? and whabt about $Px$ which is finite dimensional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define projection $P_n$ on $\ell^2(\Bbb N)$ such that $$P_n(x_1,x_2,...)=(0,...,0,x_n,x_{n+1},...)$$
for $x=(x_1,x_2,...)\in\ell^2(\Bbb N)$. 
We show that  $P_n\to 0$ (sot).

For each $x\in \ell^2(\Bbb N)$, $\epsilon>0 $ there is $n_0>0$  such that $\sum_{n>n_0}|x_n|^2 < \epsilon$. This shows that $\|P_nx\|<\epsilon$ for $n>n_0$.